# Pass wchar_t strings from/to native plugin - only works on Windows?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

What I basically want to do is pass a `string` object to a native plugin and also get a `string` object back (not necessarily from/to the same function, but this doesn't matter after all).

After quite some work I've settled to something like this (simplified example):

```cpp
EXPORT const wchar_t* myNativeFunction(const wchar_t* param)
{
    // Allocate the memory for the return value (to be freed by the Mono Runtime)
#ifdef WIN32
    wchar_t *result = static_cast<wchar_t *>(CoTaskMemAlloc((result_length + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)));
#else
    wchar_t *result = static_cast<wchar_t *>(malloc((result_length + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)));
#endif

    // Here I'd copy the actual results with a length of 'result_length'
    return result;
}
```

The C# backend in a Unity script looks like this:

```
[DllImport(nativeLibrary, EntryPoint = "myNativeFunction", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string myNativeFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string param);
```

When compiled and running under Windows this works just fine. I get the expected string to the native library and I get the correct string back, no matter whether there are non-ANSI characters in there or not.

However, trying the same code under MacOS Sierra now, this doesn't seem to work properly. For simplification, I've shortened a test function to only return `L"Test"` copied to the output buffer (`result` in the example above). However, in Unity I receive a string `"T"` only.

Overall, this looks like some weird encoding issue to me, but I can't nail it down. Did I miss anything?

**Update:** I've been able to identify the issue and it's indeed an encoding problem. Mono will *always* assume the width of `wchar_t` is 2 bytes (which it is on Windows), but this will break on Unix and MacOS, since these use `wchar_t`, which is 4 bytes wide. **Looking for a neat solution that doesn't involve too much overhead.**

Comment: The fact that you get just `T` from `"Test"` on MacOS makes me think that on that platform the Unicode format used is UTF-8 (instead of UTF-16 as on Windows), so the UTF-16-encoded `T`'s `\0` byte is interpreted as an end-of-string `NUL`-terminator in UTF-8 format, so the string gets truncated at the `T`. You may want to further investigate the Unicode format used on MacOS (I have almost zero knowledge on that platform). HTH.

Comment: @Mr.C64 Yes, those are exactly my thoughts and I'm a MacOS noob myself. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting the question I spent quite a few hours trying to implement proper (and dynamic) conversion based on the `codecvt` header in combination with `std::wstring_convert`. While this worked great, it had one major flaw: As of time of this writing, `std::wstring_convert` seems to be missing in all (otherwise C++11 compliant) compilers, except Visual Studio and Clang (using libc++). So this might have been a standard compliant solution, yet it's not really practical if it's almost impossible to use and still requires you to jump hoops (personally I gave up trying to cross-compile x86 code in this setup under Debian).

So what I ended up with instead is my own and very simple reimplementation of the conversion. Under Windows it won't do anything and just pass strings directly. It's also a lot more convenient to use compared to `std::wstring_convert`.

```
#if WIN32 // wchar_t *is* UTF-16
#define allocate(x) CoTaskMemAlloc(x)

std::wstring convert(const char16_t* text) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(text);
}

std::u16string convert(const wchar_t* text) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(text);
}

#else
#define allocate(x) malloc(x)

std::wstring convert(const char16_t* text) {
    std::wstring ret;
    const std::size_t maxlen = std::char_traits<char16_t>::length(text);
    if (maxlen == 0)
        return ret;

    ret.reserve(maxlen);

    for (char16_t s = *text; s; s = *(++text)) {
        if (s < 0xd800) {
            ret += s;
        }
        else {
            wchar_t v = (s - 0xd800) * 0x400;
            s = *(++text);
            v += (s - 0xdc00) + 0x10000;
            ret += v;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

std::u16string convert(const wchar_t* text) {
    std::u16string ret;
    const std::size_t minlen = std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(text);
    if (minlen == 0)
        return ret;

    ret.reserve(minlen);

    for (wchar_t v = *text; v; v = *(++text)) {
        if (v < 0x10000) {
            ret += v;
        }
        else {
            ret += (v - 0x10000) / 0x400 + 0xd800;
            ret += (v - 0x10000) % 0x400 + 0xdc00;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

#endif
```

The usage is rather straightforward:

```
void StringFromCSharp(const char16_t* text) {
    const std::wstring wtext(convert(text));
    SomeWideCharStuff(wtext.c_str());
}

const char16_t* StringToCSharp() {
    const std::wstring(SomeWideCharReturningStuff());
    const std::u16string converted(convert(buffer));   
    char16_t *result = static_cast<char16_t*>(allocate((converted.length() + 1) * sizeof(char16_t)));
    memcpy(result, converted.c_str(), (converted.length() + 1) * sizeof(char16_t));
    return result;
}
```

Of course there's room for optimization and depending on the actual use case there might be some better ways to do this to a void reallocations etc.

Despite that, feel free to use this in your own projects, but keep in mind I might have missed some important point somewhere, although it's running fine for me so far.